# Can I use Sqoop to import data from SQL Server to Azure blob storage

Tags: sql-server, azure-blob-storage, parquet, sqoop

Is there anyway we can import tables from SQL Server database into Azure Blob storage in .parquet file format using Sqoop utility?

Does sqoop accept the destination as wasb(s):// protocol to point to Azure blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an HDInsight cluster pointing to an existing blob storage, use sqoop for the transfer and then delete the cluster, the data will be there, in the blob storage. This is a possible work around.